# What's the difference between Obj x = Obj(n) and Obj x(n) in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I can't seem to find anything online about the differences between these two. Almost every teaching source online (learncpp.com, cplusplus.com etc) seem to all use `Obj x(n);` to initialize `Obj x`, but when I use `Obj x = Obj(n)`, my compiler doesn't complain and I see no difference. Is there actually a difference, or is it just a style choice?

Comment: In the original question the answers were pre c++11. I have added an answer which may be more relevant according to the current standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
Obj x(n);
```

is called [Direct Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). It calls the constructor that can accept `n` as an argument to initialize `x`.

Using

```
Obj x = Obj(n);
```

is called [Copy Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). In theory, this constructs a temporary `Obj` using `n` and calls the copy constructor to initialize `x`. Some compilers are able to optimize away the temporary.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I couldn't figure out what these two cases were called. Now I can read the links.

Answer (score 0):

`Obj x(n);` declared `x` as an `Obj`, and then constructs it.

`Obj x = Obj(n)` declares `x` as an `Obj`, then initializes it to the result of the construction of a temporary.

The first case is faster and generates less machine code.

Comment: Not true, any decent compiler will optimize away the temporary.

Comment: Re: "The first case is faster and generates less machine code": Is this necessarily the case? I thought that compilers were allowed to perform [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) in cases like this?

Comment: So, if the compiler does perform the optimizations you're talking about, then is it just a style choice? Is there any reason I shouldn't use whichever one I like the looks of more?

Comment: I was going to mention the possibility of optimizing away the temporary, however I'm concerned that it's not really safe to do so.  Admittedly a constructor that was written in such a way that that optimization would be a bad idea, but would be legal C++.